# data type mismatch in criteria exception in C#

Tags: c#

i am making an application in which i insert a customer_Id with Double datatype in a Textbox1.

i use the customer_ID's value to access the database of respective customer_ID.
i had converted the value of Textbox1 into Double datatype using

```
double cust_ID;  
Cust_ID=Convert.ToDouble(Textbox1.Text);
```

and the query is

```
string s="select * from Customer where Customer_ID='"+Cust_ID+"'";
```

But yet i am getting the data type mismatch in criteria exception error.

Comment: Why are you using a double for ID? IDs shouldn't have a decimal point.

Comment: What is the data type in your DB? You may not need the single quotes surrounding the Cust_ID in your select.

Comment: But yes @Blam, a more valid point than mine!

Comment: He should be using parameters for in the db query.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the value in single quites.  The following should work:

```
string s="select * from Customer where Customer_ID="+Cust_ID;
```

However, everyone else is also right - You shouldn't be using a double for an ID.  IDs should always be an `int` or a `long` depending on how many items you expect.

Comment: +1 ... and as others have said, `cust_ID` should most likely be an `int` or possibly a `long`. But definitely not a `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an integer instead of a double for the ID.

Comment: While this is good advice, the problem is simply that he is putting his double in quotes instead of just passing in the raw double.

Comment: @jjnguy: I don't think that the quotes are the problem - single quotes are optional but allowed in most databases. I think the problem is that using doubles as IDs can easily introduce representation errors causing two IDs that appear to have the same value to compare unequal. But the question is not clear enough to be 100% sure what the problem is.